# How to sort multiple keys of a single citation command according to date while using sorting=none

Tags: biblatex

I am using `biblatex` with the `numeric-comp` style and the `sorting=none` option.
Therefore, the references appear in the same order as they are cited. However, when I cite multiple publications together `\cite{key1,key2,key3}` I would like them to be sorted according to to the publication date (oldest first). `biblatex` has the `sortcites` option that is switched on by `numeric-comp` and in principle actives sorting for citations with multiple keys but is counteracted by the global `sorting=none`. How do I specify a sorting option just within multi key citations?

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[style=numeric-comp]{biblatex}
\ExecuteBibliographyOptions{
  sorting=none,
% sortcites % activated by numeric-comp
}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@misc{key0,
  author   = {Unrelated},
  title    = {Before},
  year     = {2010},
}
@misc{key1,
  author   = {Young},
  title    = {Third},
  year     = {2020},
  addendum = {should be [4]},
}
@misc{key2,
  author   = {Middle},
  title    = {Second},
  year     = {2010},
  addendum = {should be [3]},
}
@misc{key3,
  author   = {Old},
  title    = {First},
  year     = {2000},
  addendum = {should be [2]},
}
@misc{key4,
  author   = {Unrelated},
  title    = {After},
  year     = {2010},
}
\end{filecontents}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\begin{document}
Unrelated before \cite{key0}.
Discovered by \cite{key1,key2,key3}.
Unrelated after \cite{key4}.
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is something that works for the MWE you posted, but I'm not sure if it is enough for your real-world documents.

It is enough to define a sorting scheme that sorts primarily by citation order but breaks ties by `ynt` sort order. Since citations that were cited in the same go in a `\cite` all have the same cite order this appears to produce the expected result in this case.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[sortcites=true,style=numeric-comp]{biblatex}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\DeclareSortingTemplate{none-ynt}{
  \sort{\citeorder}
  \sort[final]{
    \field{sortkey}
  }
  \sort{
    \field{sortyear}
    \field{year}
    \literal{9999}
  }
  \sort{
    \field{sortname}
    \field{author}
    \field{editor}
    \field{translator}
    \field{sorttitle}
    \field{title}
  }
  \sort{
    \field{sorttitle}
    \field{title}
  }
}

\ExecuteBibliographyOptions{sorting=none-ynt}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@misc{key0,
  author   = {Unrelated},
  title    = {Before},
  year     = {2010},
}
@misc{key1,
  author   = {Young},
  title    = {Third},
  year     = {2020},
  addendum = {should be [4]},
}
@misc{key2,
  author   = {Middle},
  title    = {Second},
  year     = {2010},
  addendum = {should be [3]},
}
@misc{key3,
  author   = {Old},
  title    = {First},
  year     = {2000},
  addendum = {should be [2]},
}
@misc{key4,
  author   = {Unrelated},
  title    = {After},
  year     = {2010},
}
\end{filecontents}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\begin{document}
Unrelated before \cite{key0}.
Discovered by \cite{key1,key3,key2}.
Unrelated after \cite{key4}.
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image: Unrelated before [1]. Discovered by [2–4]. Unrelated after [5].]

Comment: I have applied this solution to some of my documents and it seems to work well. What kind of corner cases do you expect to be potentially problematic?

Comment: @JanHajer The one case I thought about turned out to be absolutely no issue. So at the moment: none.

Answer (score 0):

`sortcites` means that `\cite{}` sorts according to the currently active reference context sorting. So, if you want standard date sorting for cites and cite order for the bibliography:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[sortcites=true,sorting=ynt,style=numeric-comp]{biblatex}
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@misc{key0,
  author   = {Unrelated},
  title    = {Before},
  year     = {2010},
}
@misc{key1,
  author   = {Young},
  title    = {Third},
  year     = {2020},
  addendum = {should be [4]},
}
@misc{key2,
  author   = {Middle},
  title    = {Second},
  year     = {2010},
  addendum = {should be [3]},
}
@misc{key3,
  author   = {Old},
  title    = {First},
  year     = {2000},
  addendum = {should be [2]},
}
@misc{key4,
  author   = {Unrelated},
  title    = {After},
  year     = {2010},
}
\end{filecontents}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\begin{document}
Unrelated before \cite{key0}.
Discovered by \cite{key1,key2,key3}.
Unrelated after \cite{key4}.
\newrefcontext[sorting=none]
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

Comment: I tried `\newrefcontext` before, for me it just redefines the global sorting scheme. Therefore, it does not allow me to specify a special sorting scheme for multi key citations.

Comment: Are you sure? I have put in a full MWE now and this gives me exactly what you want - multicites are sorted `ynt` and bibliography is sorted by citation order.

Comment: I have copied your MWE example and get {Before, Third, Second, First, After} instead of  {Before, First, Second, Third, After}, in hopefully self-explaining notation.

Comment: This answer works in the sense that the citations are sorted by `ynt` order, but the citation *number* is determined purely by the sorting of the bibliography (`sorting=none`), which means that the order in which one gives the key in the `\cite` ultimately matters.